# Javascript 'SUPER' fizzbuzz

Tags: javascript, arrays, fizzbuzz

So I am attempting the good ole 'FizzBuzz' challenge in JS. However, I'm trying to add to it as I was able to complete the first challenge. For those unfamiliar with the 'FizzBuzz' challenge. Initially you want to print numbers `1..100` and those divisible by `3` prints the word `Fizz` instead of `3`; Those divisible by `5` => `Buzz`; and those divisible by both => `FizzBuzz`. What I'm trying to do is create a function that accepts an array, and returns the array with the appropriate strings in place. For example:

```
function super_fizzbuzz(array){
    var super_array = [];

    for (var array=1; array<=array.length; array++)
    {
        if (array % 15 == 0)
            super_array.push("FizzBuzz");
        else if (array % 5 == 0)
            super_array.push("Buzz");
        else if (array % 3 == 0)
            super_array.push("Fizz");
        else
            super_array.push(array);
    }
    return super_array;
    }

    console.log(super_fizzbuzz([3,10,15,19]));
```

So ideally, the answer should return `["Fizz", "Buzz", "FizzBuzz", 19]`, however it is just returning an empty array. I just did this in Ruby and I was able to get it work no problem. Trying to translate my ruby skills into practicing JS and familiarizing myself a little more with it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your `array` is trying to be both an array and its index. Once `array = 1`, then `array.length` is `undefined`, and `1 <= undefined` is `false`; the loop finishes before it has even begun. `super_array` remains at its starting value `[]`.

Rename your loop variable. Also, arrays start from `0`, not `1`, and finish at `< array.length`, not at `<=`.

Comment: Also change `super_array.push(array);` to `super_array.push(array[<<your index variable>>]);`

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
for (var array = 1; array <= array.length; array++)
```

you've overwritten the value of your function parameter, called "array", by assigning `1` to it.  There's no `.length` property of a number, so the loop never executes a single iteration.

If you want to iterate through the values in the array you pass in, then use an index variable (one with a **different** name from the array parameter), and then use it to access the elements:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] % 15 == 0)
          super_array.push("FizzBuzz");
      // etc
```

Comment: @Pointy Great explanation. I understand this a lot better. I'm REALLY new to JS so this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go**

```
function super_fizzbuzz(array){
          var super_array = [];

          for (var i=0; i<=array.length-1; i++)
          {
              if (array[i] % 15 == 0)
                  super_array.push("FizzBuzz");
              else if (array[i] % 5 == 0)
                  super_array.push("Buzz");
              else if (array[i] % 3 == 0)
                  super_array.push("Fizz");
              else
                  super_array.push(array[i]);
          }
          return super_array;
          }

          console.log(super_fizzbuzz([3,10,15,19]));
```

Comment: An extra `undefined` in the result; `<=` should be `<`.

Comment: @Amadan oops took care of it